# how to float a throbber/progress bar over greyed-out form using jquery css?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, drupal, progress-bar

I am trying to create a throbber that sits above a form when the form is submitting data to the server. So far my method of using jquery's css function works successfully for making the form appear greyed-out but I cant superimpose a throbber/progress wheel image over the top..is this the way to go or is there something Im doing wrong?

Here is my sample code in a .js external file..

```
(function($) { 

Drupal.behaviors.progress = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

 $(".form-submit").click(function()
  {
    $("#tripbuilder-form").css({'background-color':'white',
                    'opacity': '0.5'
                    });
    $("body").css({
                    'background-image': 'url(ajax-loader.gif)',
                    'background-position': 'center',
                    'z-index': '100'
                    });



  });
  }
};


})(jQuery);
```

Ive experimented with

- putting quotes around the url of the image (double and single quotes)
- ive also tried putting the background-image statements in the section related to the form instead of the body

..but all with no luck. Im thinking its the fact its a background property and so the image is effectively being hidden - in that case what is the preferred method of achieving the effect of having a progress bar image float above a greyed out form during processing? Any help much appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try creating a throbber div and have that div sit over the whole page (z-index) and set the throbber in that.

Setting the background image as you have it will still put the image behind everything because it's the background of the body.  Just now the body has a z-index of 100, which moves everything up.

Something like:

```
$(".form-submit").click( function( ) {
    $('<div>').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '0',
        'left': '0',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        'background-image': 'url(ajax-loader.gif)',
        'background-position': 'center',
        'z-index': '100'
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: i think Ive sort of got this working (I can get the background image to change color for example) but havent quite got the image to show up..but I think this will work - thanks!!

Comment: If this worked, you should make this as the accepted answer.  But glad you got it working.  =)

Comment: I can use this code to change the background color but i havent got the background image working yet..I need to check if the image  filename/path/location etc are okay

Comment: Unfortunately I just havent been able to get this to work..ive experimented with placing the image in different directories and using different paths and adding quotes etc but with no luck - I dont know why it doesnt work unfortunately..

Comment: The image path is relative to wherever that file is.  For instance, if that file is called /path/index.html, then the image would be found at /path/ajax-loader.gif.  If this script is being pulled in via javascript then the path is relative to the html file that is pulling in that javascript.  Can you put something in jsfiddle so I can better help you debug?

Comment: I have put the image in the same directory as the .js file..this code lives inside Drupal so the html is being generated from a Drupal module file which I think is also in the same directory..

Comment: I'm not sure how drupal works with paths, but one thing you could try is using a full path to the image like `url(http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg)`